# Exception & Error push notification with python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, push-notification, runtime-error

I am running an experiment with different electronic equipments. I have my script (named as "MyScript" onwards, Python3.7 and W10) for collecting data remotely. The point is that it takes several hours and sometimes it occurs an ExceptionError, SysError or KeyboardInterrupt and the script stops obviously.

My idea is to use a Push notification, if any of the errors and exceptions happen, to my mobile phone so I can restart the script and not waste time. However I do not how to code it... I guess that should be something like that:

```
SendPushNotification():
    "This function sends the notification"

if "any Exception, Error or TimeOut occurs":
   #MyScript
   SendPushNotification():
```

Thank you very much and I will appreciate your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
try:
    MainScript()
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    PushNotification("An ERROR has occured!!!")
    DoSomething1()
    DoAnotherThing()
```